# How do you separate values out from an object?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wan to get a range and place it onto another sheet using append row, but it is returning objects...I want to separate out each value and place each value into the next cell in a row.

```
var value1 = Sheet1.getRange('B3:B8').getValues();
var value7 = Sheet1.getRange('B6').getValue();
sheet2.appendRow([value1,value2]);
```

Doing this returns an object for "value1".  How might I split up what is found in the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value1  = Sheet1.getRange('B3:B8').getValues()
               .map(function(row){ return row[0];});
var value2 = Sheet1.getRange('B6').getValue();
var values = value1.concat(value2);
sheet2.appendRow(values);
```

Comment: If this is a longer explanation than I think, I will create a new question... but what if my range is more than just one column? For instance, 'B3:I20'.  How would I make the "map" then, so that I could reference cells by row AND column?

Comment: var data =     otherSheet.getRange("B3:I20").getValues().map(function(row){ return     row[0];});
   
         var value1 = data[1,1].valueOf();
     var value2 = data[1,2].valueOf();
     var value3 = data[0,0].valueOf();
     var value4 = data[1,4].valueOf();
     var value5 = data[1,5].valueOf();

Comment: you would not use map for this. I used map to convert column to row. I think you had better ask a new question.